# How to get color index change in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Below is the code that successfully works for changing the background color of a cell in VBA Excel.

```
Sub ColorChange()
    For i = 1 To 4
        Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = i + 2
    Next i
End Sub
```

Can anyone help in getting how to change the DataGridView cells background color through this color index approach in VB.Net

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are two entirely different beasts.  You will need to read the documentation for the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background colour of a cell by setting `dgv.Rows(x).Cells(y).Style.BackColor`, or in your case, in your loop, you do:

```
    dgv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```

Where `dgv` is your `DataGridView` in both respective cases. (And you change the colour to what you want, such as Color.Blue, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the color constantly in a loop. So tried it using FromArgb and it worked successfully.

`DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(a, b, c)`

Thanks for the help